# Trouble upgrading from 9.5.11 to 10

Tags: 10

I already used the Upgrade module and cleared everything on there so that I am at 100%. Now, I am using the upgrade guide for 9 to 10, as found at: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/how-to-upgrade-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10

I'm including below: the command I ran, the errors I received, and a copy of my json file. Please let me know if there is anything else you need to help me run down these errors.

I run: composer update --dry-run

Here's the errors I get:

```
  Problem 1    - drupal/adminimal_theme 1.7.0 requires drupal/seven ~1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/seven[1.0.0].    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/seven 1.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core[8.9.0, ..., 8.9.10] require symfony-cmf/routing ^1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0, 1.4.1].
- drupal/core[8.8.0, ..., 8.8.12] require zendframework/zend-feed ^2.12 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-feed[2.12.0, ..., 2.19.0], zendframework/zend-feed[2.12.0].    - zendframework/zend-feed[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-feed[2.12.0, ..., 2.12.3] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
- symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require php ^5.3.9|^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
- drupal/core[8.9.11, ..., 8.9.20] require php ^7.0.8 -> your php version (8.1.27) does not satisfy that requirement.    - drupal/core[9.0.10, ..., 9.0.14] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-feed[2.13.0, ..., 2.14.1] require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.1.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires drupal/viewsreference ^1.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/viewsreference[1.8.0].
- drupal/core-recommended 10.2.2 requires drupal/core 10.2.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.2.2].
- Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.2.2 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended 10.2.3 requires drupal/core 10.2.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.2.3].
- Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.2.3 (conflict analysis result)
- Root composer.json requires drupal/adminimal_theme ^1.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/adminimal_theme[1.6.0, 1.7.0].
- drupal/core-recommended 10.2.1 requires drupal/core 10.2.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.2.1].
- Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.2.1 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/adminimal_theme 1.6.0 requires drupal/core ^8.8 || ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11].
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0, ..., 10.2.3].
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.7.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0, ..., 10.2.3].
- drupal/core-recommended 10.2.0 requires drupal/core 10.2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.2.0].
- Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.2.0, 10.2.1, 10.2.2, 10.2.3].
```

Here's my json file:

```
{
"name": "drupal/recommended-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^2.2",
    "drupal/address": "^2.0",
    "drupal/addtoany": "^2.0",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.4",
    "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.6",
    "drupal/anchor_link": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/asset_injector": "^2.19",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^6.0",
    "drupal/block_class": "^2.0",
    "drupal/block_field": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.25",
    "drupal/bootstrap_paragraphs": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/bootstrap_styles": "^1.1",
    "drupal/captcha": "^2.0",
    "drupal/charts": "^5.0",
    "drupal/chosen": "^4.0",
    "drupal/classy_paragraphs": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/colorbox": "^2.0",
    "drupal/content_access": "^2.0",
    "drupal/context": "^4.1",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10.2",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^10.2",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.2",
    "drupal/crop": "^2.3",
    "drupal/csv_serialization": "^2.1",
    "drupal/ctools": "^4.0",
    "drupal/devel": "^5.0",
    "drupal/draggableviews": "^2.0",
    "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.6",
    "drupal/ds": "^3.13",
    "drupal/dynamic_entity_reference": "^1.16",
    "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^2.0",
    "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^2.2",
    "drupal/embed": "^1.7",
    "drupal/entity": "^1.4",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.10",
    "drupal/entity_clone": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.2",
    "drupal/entity_print": "^2.6",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.10",
    "drupal/entity_type_clone": "^1.7",
    "drupal/eu_cookie_compliance": "^1.24",
    "drupal/extlink": "^1.7",
    "drupal/fakeobjects": "^1.2",
    "drupal/faqfield": "^7.1",
    "drupal/feeds": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/feeds_tamper": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.4",
    "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.1",
    "drupal/file_browser": "^1.3",
    "drupal/file_download_link": "^2.0",
    "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.26",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.1",
    "drupal/google_analytics_reports": "^3.1",
    "drupal/google_analytics_reports_api": "^3.1",
    "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.3",
    "drupal/imce": "^3.0",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/jquery_ui": "^1.6",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^2.0",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_datepicker": "^1.3",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_slider": "^1.1",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_touch_punch": "^1.0",
    "drupal/layout_builder_iframe_modal": "^1.3",
    "drupal/layout_paragraphs": "^2.0",
    "drupal/link_target": "^1.4",
    "drupal/linkit": "^6.1",
    "drupal/login_destination": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@RC",
    "drupal/maxlength": "^2.0",
    "drupal/media_library_importer": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/menu_block": "^1.10",
    "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.3",
    "drupal/metatag": "^2.0",
    "drupal/migrate_source_csv": "^3.6",
    "drupal/module_filter": "^3.2",
    "drupal/node_export": "^1.0",
    "drupal/page_manager": "^4.0@beta",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.16",
    "drupal/paragraphs_edit": "^3.0",
    "drupal/paragraphs_features": "^1.16",
    "drupal/paragraphs_sets": "^3.0",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.12",
    "drupal/profile": "^1.7",
    "drupal/quick_node_clone": "^1.15",
    "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.2",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.9",
    "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/scheduler": "^2.0",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.23",
    "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^4.1",
    "drupal/smart_trim": "^2.1",
    "drupal/smtp": "^1.0",
    "drupal/super_login": "^2.1",
    "drupal/superfish": "^1.7",
    "drupal/svg_image": "^3.0",
    "drupal/tablefield": "^2.3",
    "drupal/taxonomy_import": "^2.0",
    "drupal/taxonomy_manager": "^2.0",
    "drupal/text_field_formatter": "^2.0",
    "drupal/token": "^1.13",
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^3.2",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/upgrade_status": "*",
    "drupal/views_aggregator": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_bootstrap": "^4.4",
    "drupal/views_bulk_edit": "^2.6",
    "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^4.2",
    "drupal/views_conditional": "^1.9",
    "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.4",
    "drupal/views_field_view": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_load_more": "^2.0@alpha",
    "drupal/viewsreference": "^1.8",
    "drupal/webform": "^6.2",
    "drush/drush": "^12"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
        "drupal/core-project-message": true,
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
    }
},
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "web/"
        }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "web/libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, youâ€™ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
},
"require-dev": {
    "drupal/core-dev": "^10"
}
```

}